# How MIN/MAX function works in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to understand how MIN/MAX function calculates value in backed in sql

Lets say I have below table Duplicate

```
ID  NAME
1   A
2   A
3   A
4   A
5   A
6   B
7   B
8   B
9   B
10  B
11  C
12  C
13  C
14  C
```

SO when I run a below query

```
SELECT MAX(ID), NAME FROM Duplicate
  GROUP BY NAME
```

Does sql engine finds first MAX value of ID in every group and then finds MAX ID out of those Grouped records ? Is it correct or something else happens ?

Comment: Your assumption sounds largely correct to me.  Why don't you run the query and see for yourself?

Comment: I would suggest that you edit your question to demonstrate that you now what the result set looks like.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, The result surely would be MAX id (14) from the above data, but my concern is how it gets calculate in sql engine before it comes before us on screen ..?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I have run the query and it gives me the correct result set. But how should I observe this behind calculations ?

Comment: @Joy . . . So you don't understand how the code works.  It returns multiple rows.

Comment: what is the result set of your query an what is unclear?

Comment: @miracle173 what do you mean by result set ..? It should be the Max ID, the concern here is how its getting calculated behind the scenes ...?

Comment: There are three distinct names, so the query will return the max ID for name `A` (5), `B` (10) and `C` (14). I expect it will use a hashing approach. You may get more specific replies if you post the results and execution plan and ask about the sections you are interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll see something like this in Oracle

```
SQL> set autotrace traceonly explain
SQL> select owner, max(object_id)
  2  from   t
  3  group by owner;

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 47235625

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |    37 |   407 |   431   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY     |      |    37 |   407 |   431   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| T    | 78939 |   847K|   427   (1)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

"group by hash".  This a mechanism via which we can avoid a massive sorting cost to perform aggregation (min, max, etc etc).

Conceptually its like this:

- Read first row
- Hash the group by column ("owner" in my case)
- Lets say the hash value is 1234.
- Store value of "object_id" in bucket 1234.

then

- Read next row
- Hash the group by column ("owner" in my case)
- Lets say the hash value is 5678.
- Store value of "object_id" in bucket 5678.

then

- Read next row
- Hash the group by column ("owner" in my case)
- Lets say the hash value is 1234 (ie, same value is row 1).
- Compare object_id value with existing object_id in bucket 5678.  If it's larger, then replace it, otherwise ignore and move on.

So you can see we can identify the max value without sorting - just a single scan of the all the data.

Comment: Super ...! Thanks for sharing...! 

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what DB you're using, but for Teradata, which distributes table rows in a parallel manner, a simple aggregation with GROUP BY typically will do:

1. Aggregate rows (local)
2. Redistribute rows
3. Sort rows
4. Aggregate rows (global)
5. Return final result

What DBMS are you using?  Can you run an EXPLAIN on your query to see what the query plan is?  That would give you some idea.

Comment: I'm using Oracle..!

Comment: I've never used it, so not sure how helpful it will be...but this may help: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/ex_plan.htm#i17492